# Laravel. How to call specific array in object when using Session?

Tags: laravel

Please take a look first to my picture to see data structure. I would like to call 'event_name'

i have tried :

```
$session->event_name;
```

This not working. 
[image]

Comment: you mean `$session['event_name'];`

Comment: Thank you it's working with that code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot displays an array, therefore the value would be accessible like so:

```
$session['event_name'];
```

But if you are using the Laravel session tools: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/session#retrieving-data

You can do this:

```
$session->get('event_name');
```